# Two Weapon Fighting Probability

Tags: pathfinder-1e, two-weapon-fighting

I'm thinking about taking the Two Weapon Fighting feat.  I'm a 7th level unchained rogue with the knife fighter and scout archetypes.  So far I've concentrated on optimising my movement around the battlefield, with the Dodge, Mobility, Spring Attack, Fleet and Underfoot (I'm a Halfling) feats.  Also my Scout archetype allows me to add Sneak Attack damage whenever I charge.  I  get have a +11 to-hit bonus with my preferred (light) weapon, and do 1d3 + 4d8 (sneak) damage.  I reckon I do on average

```
0.6 * 24 = 14.4 damage to an opponent with an armor class of 20
```

If I take TWF, my to-hit will drop to +9.  So I'll do

```
0.5 * 24 = 18 doubled = 36
```

So taking TWF seems a no-brainer.  Are my calculations correct, and are there any other factors I should take into consideration?

Comment: I know that 3.5 added a feat for using TWF while moving, in player handbook 2 iirc . I'm positive that if you search around you may stumble upon the pathfinder equivalent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**are there any other factors I should take into consideration?**

Consider the following points:

This only works if you're doing a Full-Attack. Using a Full Attack generally means that you started your turn adjacent to an enemy, and will end it there, too. You might be giving your opponents a lot more freedom to beat on you, in return for that extra damage.
It also means you have less ability to move around to get your Sneak Attack, although how big a problem this is depends on the rest of your character and team.

Also, you'll need to invest in 2 high-quality weapons to make this work properly, which might require a substantial chunk of your wealth or means you'll be using a set of slightly weaker weapons compared to a single one.

Also, once you get multiple attacks per round, the huge advantage will start dropping off a bit, since you can only make one extra attack per round.

If you're okay with those factors, then Two-Weapon Fighting is probably a good bet for you to increase your damage output.

Comment: OK, I'd missed that TWF is only available with a full attack.  The description on page 202 just says "If you wield a second weapon in your off hand, you can get one extra attack per round with that weapon", but I now see the text under "Full Attack".  I've concentrated on my maneuverability, so this is probably not the way for me to go.  Thanks.